# Can I run Processing.org Python sketch from a Jupyter Notebook and pass data?

Tags: python, processing, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I was looking for a way to run "Processing in Python" scripts out of Jupyter notebooks so I installed calysto_processing. Then I discovered it wants to speak Javascript but I wanted to stay in Python. I want to launch and feed a sketch so the user can change the POV as the data loads, changes, etc.

```
import numpy as np
import processing as pg

aData = np.load("myDataFile",...)

sketch = pg.launch("mySketch")

while True:
    sketch.update(aData.getNextBatch())
```

Answer (score 4):

[Processing.py](https://py.processing.org/) runs on Python 2.7 on [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) ("Python for the Java Platform") so that it can directly access the Processing (Java) API.

For this reason, your Jupyter install would need a JVM in order for Processing.py to run and an in-browser Java sketch window to draw. Something might be possible with scijava-jupyter-kernel, which I believe has Jython and java.awt support, but you are going down the road of Java-in-the-browser, which may not be the way you wanted to go.

An alternative might be to look at integrating [p5py](https://github.com/p5py/p5) -- "a Python package based on the core ideas of Processing."

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am trying to distance myself from Java and focus on Python. Processing has a great library of visualization tools and I was hoping to integrate the two.

Comment: Unfortunately, p5py graphics are [glfw](http://www.glfw.org/) based, so desktop rather than browser friendly. You could have a Jupyter notebook send data to a desktop sketch via files / websockets / OSC etc. The easiest way by far to do Processing IN the browser (and in Jupyter) is JavaScript -- e.g. p5.js.